# How do I ensure server request is complete before page redirect?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, xmlhttprequest

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, my main question boils down to this: if you issue an AJAX request to some server (in this case Google's), but then the client leaves the page before the server completes the request, is it possible (or likely) that the server would abort the request as well, or would the server try to complete the request (in spite of having no one to respond to any more)?

Feel free to read the rest for all the specifics, if you want.

---

I am using Google Analytics on a page that is meant to immediately redirect. Since the Google javascript file `ga.js` is loaded asynchronously, I need to make sure that all the script tags that are added dynamically by the javascript are tracked and that the page redirect only happens after those scripts complete. I already handled that part.

The file `ga.js` seems to make a request to a `__utm.gif` file with parameters, which is what performs the actual tracking. That request obviously isn't being made from a file I can control, so here are my questions:

First of all, is the request asynchronous (I suspect it is)? Secondly, how can I make sure that that request has time to complete before I redirect the page (I'd prefer not to simply redirect after "enough time" has passed)? Would the request still complete if the originating page redirected before the request was finished (after all, I don't need any data back from Google)?

**EDIT:** Here's my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <title>Redirecting...</title>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */

        // Holds a value for each script. When all the values contained in this array are true, all loading has completed.
        var scripts = [];

        function scriptDetectLoaded(script)
        {
            scripts.push({ loaded: false, element: script });
            var index = scripts.length - 1;

            // Will set this script as loaded
            var callback = function ()
            {
                //console.log("Script with index " + index + " finished loading");
                scripts[index].loaded = true;
            };

            // For most browsers
            script.onload = callback;
            // For IE
            script.onreadystatechange = function ()
            {
                if (this.readyState == "complete")
                    callback();
            };

            return index;
        }

        /* ]]> */
     </script>

     <!-- Google analytics code -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-MY_ID-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function ()
        {
            //debugger;
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            scriptDetectLoaded(ga); var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>
        <p>Please enable JavaScript and refresh this page. Our site won't work correctly without it.</p>
        <p><a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+enable+javascript" target="_blank">How do I enable JavaScript?</a></p>
    </noscript>

<!-- Google Code for New Account Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    //debugger;
    var google_conversion_id = SOME_ID;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "2";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "SOME_LABEL";
    var google_conversion_value = 0;

    (function () {
        var gad = document.createElement('script'); gad.type = 'text/javascript'; gad.async = true;
        gad.src = document.location.protocol + "//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js";
        scriptDetectLoaded(gad); var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gad, s);
    })();
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<noscript>
    <div style="display:inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1056222251/?label=keCSCNO9qAIQq9jS9wM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
    </div>
</noscript>

    <!-- Redirect Page -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        //debugger;
        var url = '/console';
        var interval = 100 /*milliseconds*/;
        var timeout = 5000 /*milliseconds*/;
        var count = 0;

        // Set a repeating function that checks to ensure all the scripts have loaded.
        // Once all the scripts have loaded, redirect the page.
        var id = setInterval(function ()
        {
            count += interval;

            // Check for timeout
            if (count > timeout)
            {
                //console.log("Timed out.");
                redirect();
            }

            // Check to make sure all scripts have loaded
            for (var i = 0, len = scripts.length; i < len; i++)
            {
                if (!scripts[i].loaded)
                    return;
            }

            // If we make it here, redirect
            redirect();
        }, interval);

        function redirect()
        {
            location.replace(url);

            // Run this in case the page doesn't redirect properly.
            clearInterval(id);

            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = url;
            a.innerHTML = "Please click here to proceed";

            var p = document.getElementById("message");
            p.innerHTML = "";
            p.appendChild(a);
        }
        /* ]]> */
    </script>

    <p id="message">Please wait as we redirect the page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect before the request completes, it will be cancelled on the client side. meaning, the server may have gotten the post and acted on it, but you will not get the results. if these items are added dynamically you cannot use any onload type of functions. i would imagine the google files your adding will have some type of callback you can use that will redirect you.

edit:  if you want to load the script in a way that you will know exactly when it is done loading so you can redirect to another page i would use jquery's $.getScript function. it allows for a callback once the file has loaded then you can redirect instantly [api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript)

Comment: Right, it will be cancelled on the client side. I don't need anything back from the request, though (all I would get back is a 1x1 transparent gif, anyway) so that doesn't matter. Is it likely or possible that the _server_ would cancel the request if the client bailed? If not, I have nothing to worry about.

Comment: if you only need to "load" the file, you could use a setinterval that looks for a variable name that exists in that particular js file and redirect once it exists

Comment: post what you have between your `<script>`  tags

Comment: Most of my file is between `script` tags, so I posted the whole thing.

Comment: oh, i see what your doing.  i would use jquery's $.getScript  function.  it allows for a callback once the file has loaded then you can redirect instantly
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: I thought about putting jquery on this page a few times. I just didn't want to load it if I didn't need it. I'm pretty sure my stuff is working, but I would bet on jquery's stability over that stuff I wrote in a hurry. Just curious though, specifically in regards to an `xhr` request, will the server abort a request if the client moves on before the request can be returned?

Comment: @JohnnyCraig let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1861/discussion-between-benekastah-and-johnny-craig)

Comment: the request cannot be aborted with the client to request it. which wont happen..  sorry i have been at work and couldnt chat.  and now is time to go home. can help tomorrow if youstill are stuck

Comment: Ok. So the server will complete the request then. I edited my question to include a summarized (and hopefully clearer) version of what I was asking, btw. If I understand you right, then edit your answer to include what you just said, and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

For the tracking that depends on __utm.gif, the request shouldn't need to complete for the metrics to work. Once the browser sends the request (with all the params), GA has what it needs. So you just need to make sure that the image request fires.

If this is an interstitial page with no real content, you may be able to do something like check the length of the document's images collection; when length > 0, then you know GA has created the IMG and set its src (thereby triggering the request). Not sure about the details of that collection, but I know stuff like that used to exist; maybe it still does. In that case, a simple setInterval to perform the test and kick off the redirect should suffice.

Edit: Since the GA stuff adds scripts to the document, you can check the DOM structure to see if scripts with the proper src value exist. That may get you closer to chaining the redirect from the right kind of event.

Comment: Sadly, GA doesn't make an actual `image` element for the `gif` file I'm "requesting". They use a `gif` for a reason that's a little bit beyond me. AFAIK, they use it simply as a super-lightweight resource to make things faster, since you don't need any response from them.

Comment: Yeah, I know GA doesn't actually add the IMG to the page. But it's possible browsers track -- apart from the DOM -- sets of resources like this that the window is aware of. Check out the documentation on what PPK calls the Browser Object Model. Kind of like how browsers have a frames collection. You would then make your determination not by checking whether there is an IMG in the DOM, but by doing something like "document.images.length > 0".

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me that the image could show up in the images collection without being in the DOM. Anyway, maybe the Google script doesn't store the image anywhere, because it never shows up in `document.images`  :/

Answer (score 0):

For the current state of ga.js you can check tracking completing using this code:

```
(function (global) {

    var listeners = []
        , ImageReworked
        , ImageNative = Image
    ;

    function stringMatch(haystack, needle) {
        if (typeof needle.valueOf() === 'string' && haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1) {
            return true;
        } else if (needle instanceof RegExp && haystack.match(needle)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    global.addImageListener = function (url, handler) {
        if (!listeners.length) {
            Image = ImageReworked;
        }
        listeners.push([url, handler]);
    };

    global.removeImageListener = function (url, handler) {
        var newListeners = [];
        listeners.forEach(function (el) {
            if (url.constructor !== el[0].constructor //this will not work for object in different windows
                || el[0].toString() !== url.toString()
                || (handler && handler !== el[1])) {
                newListeners.push(el);
            }
        });
        listeners = newListeners;
        if (!listeners.length) {
            Image = ImageNative;
        }
    };

    ImageReworked = function(w, h) {
        var i = new ImageNative(w, h)
        ;

        function handler() {
            listeners.forEach(function (el) {
                var url = el[0]
                    , handler = el[1]
                ;

                if (stringMatch(i.src, url)) {
                    handler(i.src);
                }
            });
        }

        if (i.addEventListener) {
            i.addEventListener('load', handler, false);
        } else if (i.attachEvent) {
            i.attachEvent('onload', handler);
        }

        return i;
    };
})(window);
```

Usage example:

```
addImageListener(/__utm/, function (src) {
    var parameters = {};

    window.removeImageListener(new RegExp('__utm'));//see, regexp can be created by new RegExp!

    (foundParameters = src.match(/(\?|&)(.*?\=[^?&]*)/g)) && foundParameters.forEach(function (parameter) {
        var pair = parameter.replace(/^(\?|&)/, '').split('=');
        parameters[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    });
    console.log(parameters);
});

_gaq.push(['_setAccount', gaid], ['_trackPageview']);
```

But you should always keep in mind that if GA changes their tracking logic, this code will be broken.

You also should add timeout (what if load-event will never occure).

And don't use i.onload, because GA-script override this attribute.