# How do I call a JS function before any page redirect request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a wordpress gravityform. I want that when user has changes anything in any input field and after that clicks on any page redirection there should be a popup to first save your data. Here is my code. I have written the following function which will trigger the save button of the form if user click the ok button on the alert. But where should I call this function. If I call this in .bind(beforeunload), it is ignored and before unload display its own text in the popup. I also cannot call this function on every input change because it will not allow user to complete entering data in the form. What can be the appropriate solution ?

```
function confirmLeave() {
    if(!confirm("Would you like to save your data before redirecting?")) return;
    $( "#gform_submit_button_52" ).trigger( "click" );
}
```

I have tried this

[call-js-function-before-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855934/call-js-function-before-redirect)

[how-do-i-ensure-server-request-is-complete-before-page-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837022/how-do-i-ensure-server-request-is-complete-before-page-redirect)

Comment: You can't show prompts or any modal dialogs on `beforeunload`, this ability was removed from browsers for several years ago. You've to rely on the prompt the browser offers.

Comment: Thats why I have created my own popup but have not figured it out how to call it on any page redirect/page leave request

Comment: Again: "_any modal_" ... If you're doing something asynchronous (which is how the JS "modals" are implemented) on `beforeunload` handler, it is aborted. Your best bet is to save the changes anyway (use `navigator.sendBeacon` method), if you don't want to use the native prompt the browser offers.

Comment: Is there any JS solution to call my confirmLeave function on any redirection ? @Teemu

Comment: Yes, you can call any function you want, but like said before, you can't execute any asynchronous code or show any prompts.